# Install Kinesis agent on premise

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-kinesis

We want to implement a logging solution with AWS (Kinesis, Kinesis FireHoste, ES, Kibana). But we have a Hybrid environment. I saw you can install Kinesis on RHEL7, AWS AMI and Microsoft. Is it possible to install it on on-premise instances or is it only for EC2 instances?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can install on-premises. The documentation at the AWS site doesn't make it explicit, but if you go directly to [the project's github page](https://github.com/awslabs/amazon-kinesis-agent) you have instructions to install in different systems and to configure the agent.